# How to check if a line in a text file contains a certain character

Tags: python, text, character, counter

How do you check to see if a line contains a certain character at any point in the line of a text file? I currently have:

```
charCounter=0
with open('file', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'a' in line:
            charCounter=charCounter+1
```

However the only time the counter increments is when the character is the first character in the line. I need to check for the character if it appears in the line at any point.

Comment: Works for me. can you give some example data?

Comment: `if 'a' in line` should check if the string `line` contains `'a'` at any position, not just the first character. Could you provide an example where it does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Halfway tongue in check, why only count one character when you can count all of them more easily:

```
from collections import Counter

c=Counter()
with open('file') as f:
    c=Counter(ch for line in f for ch in line)

>>> c
Counter({' ': 99, '-': 85, 'e': 12, 'o': 12, '>': 11, '<': 10, 'n': 8, '\n': 7, 't': 7, 'd': 6, '/': 5, 'i': 5, 'm': 5, 'r': 4, '|': 4, 'a': 3, 'g': 3, 'f': 3, 'h': 3, '+': 2, 'T': 2, 'b': 2, 'y': 2, '!': 1, "'": 1, '.': 1, '1': 1, 'D': 1, 'J': 1, 'R': 1, 'k': 1, 'l': 1, 's': 1, 'w': 1, 'v': 1, 'x': 1})
```

Then to know your specific character count:

```
>>> c['a'] 
3
```

(in this particular file, there are 3 `'a`'`)

Or you can skip the Counter if you really only want a single character and use the same comprehension in `sum`:

```
with open('file') as f:
    c=sum(1 for line in f for ch in line if ch=='a')

>>> c
3
```

---

If you want lines that contain `'a'` you can do:

```
with open('file') as f:
    print sum(1 for line in f if 'a' in line)
```

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the problem. Here we need to count the number of lines containing the character `a`, not count the number of occurrence of the character `a`.

Comment: I added that. Thanks

Comment: The only problem is that the text file is very large. Because the file is so large it becomes difficult to do something with the counter the way you have described as running out of memory will become an issue.

Comment: That is an imaginary issue. The file is read line-by-line. The counter is only as big as the total unique characters in the file.